# Storing bounded methods that initialized and/or modified an object inside the object itself

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm currently trying to build a mechanism that stores - inside an object - the bounded function(s) that have initialized and modified it **without `inspect`**. In essence, if you imagine the following:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []

class Stages:
    def one(self):
        return Foo()

    def two(self, foo):
        foo.x = 10
        return foo

s = Stages()
foo = s.one()
foo = s.two(foo)
```

I want to be able to do:

```py
print(foo.history)
```

and be able to see the functions, `one` and `two`, and have access to their [`__self__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) - the instance `s = Stages()`.

---

My current attempt has been to use a decorator to globally store the current function being ran:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any
from functools import wraps

_func = None

def record(func: Callable):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global _func

        try:
            _func = func
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            _func = None

    return wrapper

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = [_func]

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        if not name.startswith("__") and name != "history":
            self.history += [_func]
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)

class Stages:
    @record
    def one(self):
        return Foo()

    @record
    def two(self, foo):
        foo.x = 10
        return foo

s = Stages()
foo = s.one()
foo = s.two(foo)
```

But this leads me to unbounded functions:

```py
print(foo.history)
print(s.one, s.two)
```

```
[<function Stages.one at 0x10b8ec3a0>, <function Stages.two at 0x10b8ec4c0>]
<bound method Stages.one of <__main__.Stages object at 0x10b7db280>> <bound method Stages.two of <__main__.Stages object at 0x10b7db280>>
```

My current iteration *is not* async or thread safe (as evident by `global`), and while it is not a *hard* requirement, it wouldn't hurt if it was. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `record` should probably just manually modify the `history` when you pass a `Foo` as an argument or return it.

Comment: As an aside, your uses of `global _func` outside of `def wrapper` are not necessary and would confuse people

Comment: But honestly, the most reasonable way to do this is not to rely on all kinds of behid-the-scenes magic, and just provide mutator methods, e.g. `def update(stage, func, *kwargs): ...` and then just do something like `self.history.append((stage, func))` and then just `vars(self).update(kwargs)` (maybe after some validation of `kwargs`). Also, `__init__` should accept the `stage` and `func` as well

Comment: The example above is a stripped down version of what I currently have. My first thought was to do what you mentioned in your first comment, but the repeating injection of the method into the object doesn't look ✨ nice ✨. This is just an interesting puzzle I wound up diving into, and came here seeking advice on it.

Comment: Regarding `globals`, you are right - I modified the post. Thanks for pointing it out.